Get code coverage report path from SonarQube
We have a giant monolith application. We are using SonarQube for static code coverage. We have an internal requirement to showcase code coverage as per feature level.
We have created a program which takes code coverage report (sample data extracted from Sonar UI), and generate report as per feature level. For this, we have created a mapping of class/package against feature. Program reads Sonar report, maps those classes against provided mappings in configuration.
I want to make this program a part of CI/CD but need some pointers like where SonarQube save this coverage data internally so that CI/CD job can access it.
